# Can I mass-delete REFs from components in KiCad?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad, pcb-layers, reference

I have a PCB, and it can't nearly fit all of the REF markings on F.SilkS and B.SilkS. I want to just make my own for a few components, e.g. I would write "R1-R16", rather than "R1", "R2", etc.

Is it possible to mass-delete these REFs on the silkscreen layers, and add my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since current versions of KiCAD lack of bulk edit tools in the PCB editor, I wrote [a Python script](https://github.com/SengerM/KiCAD_utils/blob/main/hide_all_reference_designators.py) that automatically hides ALL reference designators. Then I manually activate only those I need.

This script is really doing it *as it should be done*, i.e. unchecking the `Show` for the `Reference designator` field individually in each component (I see that other answers are just hiding them to show up in the editor, but not actually disabling them):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

***Edit for KiCad v6+***

You can bulk-edit text items

[image: Edit Text & Graphics Properties]

Then change the properties you like

[image: Edit Text & Graphics window]

***Original Answer for KiCad v5***

The easiest way to achieve this would be to disable the references and add your own board text on the silkscreen.

You disable reference display here
[image: Reference display KiCad]

And you will also need to disable the plotting of references here
[image: KiCad Plotting]

Comment: I didn't know you could just flat out disable them, thanks, this works perfect!

Comment: Do note, that anyone else whom ever has to work on this board, will curse you for removing all the component designators. :)

Comment: There's one big disadvantage: those designators are still present in 3D viewer.